# Sql Server - missing pfclnt.dll?

Tags: sql-server, windows-server-2003, smo

I'm getting the following error when trying to initialise the SMO objects in my application:

Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Trace.SqlTraceException: Failed to initialize object as reader. ---> System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'file:///c:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Binn\pfclnt.dll' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

This file is indeed missing from that location.

Any ideas why and where I can go about getting it?

I'm running:
SqlServer 2005
ManagementStudio 9.00.4035.00
WinServer 2003 SP2

Comment: I have a feeling its due to not having SSIS installed on my machine (thank god), but I never went back to the problem to verify that was the case...

Answer (score 1):

I experienced the same problem which was solved by switching over to x86 (from AnyCPU). It seems that the assembly is only available in 32 bit mode.

Next problem was "Mixed mode assembly is built against version 'v2.0.50727' of the runtime and cannot be loaded in the 4.0 runtime without additional configuration information."

This was solved by adding the `useLegacyV2RuntimeActivationPolicy` attribute in my app.config. I already hade the supportedRuntime node, and can't say if it's necessary for the solution to work.

```
<configuration>
  <startup useLegacyV2RuntimeActivationPolicy="true">
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.0" />
  </startup>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try to reinstall SQL Server Management Studio or update to the latest service pack to fix this kind of issue.

If it is not working, you could also upgrade to SQL Server Management Studio 2008 since it is backward compatible with SQL Server 2005.

[SQL Server 2005 SP4](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=b953e84f-9307-405e-bceb-47bd345baece)

[SQL Server Management Studio 2008 Express (also works with Standard and Enterprise editions)](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=08e52ac2-1d62-45f6-9a4a-4b76a8564a2b)